# My SQL import data wizard does not create schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The mysql workbench data import wizard imports brand new data from the mysql dump file. Is there an option to copy the schema as well? I bascically want the entire schema and data copied from one database to the another. But the import data wizard only does the data.

Comment: How did you create the dump file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create dump of tables only then transfer the data